# Always on python script with Upstart. Python used for serial communication

Tags: python, ubuntu, serial-port, upstart

First of All, I want to wish you a Merry Christmas.
I have a two problem with Upstart.

1) I need to keep a python script always on in a Linux ubuntu distro.
The script is responsable to communicate with serial port /tty/ACM0 and is essential in my application.

At boot time, Upstart launch the script (I can see this using "service myscript status"), but it don't work. If I manually type

```
service myscript stop
service myscript start
```

it work properly.

2) Sometimes happens that the device is connected but not recognized by linux. 
In that case, the script fails and upstart respawn it (and it is correct), but I would like to wait some seconds before the respawn, instead also the new process will die and there will be a lot of overhead (using top, python take 98% of CPU in this case).
The problem should be software, because the devices is always connected when the system is on.

Here my config file /etc/init/myscript.conf

```
description "...."
 author "...."

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn limit unlimited

exec python /smartwarmth/bin/Seriale.py
```

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on ServerFault(?) or AskUbuntu or Super User.

Comment: *"but it don't work"* is not very informative. Enable logging and see what happens.